# How to run a python package on pre-commit git hook

Tags: python, git, sh

How do i get iterate over the changed files (git) and apply the `flake8` and `isort` packages to this files?

```
git diff --name-only --cached | xargs python -m isort -I
```

This example above doesn't work, the error says `unrecognized arguments: -I`

I'm trying this in the `pre-commit` hook.

Comment: Searching on https://timothycrosley.github.io/isort/ shows no results for `-I`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: BTW, thanks for introducing me to isort

Comment: i read somewhere that the `-I` is used to get the argument that was generated by the command previously the `|`

Comment: So an argument to `xargs`? It would be helpful to know what you heard and where...

Answer (score 0):

Apparantly `-I` isn't a valid argument for `isort`:

https://github.com/timothycrosley/isort/blob/6b8f57b8f64676ce2125e5b3c7bb7590539287c7/isort/main.py#L25

Maybe you meant `--interactive`.

Comment: i read somewhere that the `-I` is used to get the argument that was generated by the command previously the `|`

Answer (score 0):

<s>when you run python with the `-m` flag, it terminates the options list. try moving the `-I` to before `-m`</s>

```
git diff --name-only --cached | xargs python -I -m isort
```

If you intended the `-I` to be passed to isort, it is not a valid parameter.

Instead of focusing on this `xargs` command and python invocation, let's back up and look at the problem you want to solve:

> How do i get iterate over the changed files (git) and apply the flake8 and isort packages to this files?

Here is a sample script I have used as the basis for a pre-commit hook:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

CD_UP="$(git rev-parse --show-cdup)"
MOD_FILES=($(git status --porcelain | grep -E '^[MARC]' \
             | awk '{print $2}' | tr '\r\n' ' '))
BAD_FILES=()
for MOD_FILE in "${CD_UP}${MOD_FILES[@]}"; do
    <do stuff>
    if <the result of "do stuff" was not good>; then
        BAD_FILES+=("${MOD_FILE}")
    fi
done

for f in "${BAD_FILES[@]}"; do
    echo "File failed pre-commit checks: ${f}"
done

if [ ${#BAD_FILES[*]} != 0 ]; then
  exit 1
fi
exit 0
```

This will:

- find the changes in the commit
- put them in an array
- loop through the aray, running some commands on each file
- check the result of each check, and add any failing files to BAD_FILES
- report on each file that failed
- exit with exit code 0 if no files failed (allowing `git` to proceed with the commit) or with exit code 1 if any files failed (preventing `git` from proceeding with the commit)

You need to replace `<do stuff>` with the commands to run `flake8` and `isort`, on `${MOD_FILE}`. You also need to modify the `if` statement in the loop body to check the result of your commands and determine if the file failed or passed.

just replace `.git/hooks/pre-commit` with this script (plus your modifications) and you should be good.

Comment: where the name file is used on `isort` i thought that `-I` was passing the file name as argument to `isort`